# LISP variable exchange

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How can I exchange two variables in LISP without using a third variable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
(rotatef a b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

(let ((a b) 
      (b a))
   ...)

Comment: That does not change the variables' values, it only creates new lexical bindings.

Comment: @dmitry-vk: That's often all you need.  It depends on what you're doing, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, "parallel setf":

(psetf a b b a)

Comment: A difference between `rotatef` and `psetf` is that if `a` and `b` are really more complicated forms, then `psetf` will evaluate any subforms twice, but `rotatef` will evaluate them only once, which is what one would normally want.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
(setf (values a b) (values b a))
```

Answer (score -3):

Rather gruesome method and it works only for numerical values,  but it's more general and not syntax dependent:

> a = a^b
>
> b = a^b
>
> a = a^b

Assuming that a and b were assigned before, the ^ means logical exclusive alternative.

Comment: Fascinating, the two binary numbers really pass through each other without additional space requirements.